# For loop to capture values in different named ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have been looking through multiple posts on looping through multiple named ranges and returning values to another cell. Unfortunately, I am getting stuck on how to loop through two named ranges to return the value from one named range if a cell in another named range is "X".

Below are images of the named ranges with values and the intended result in cell I46.  Please note there is no formula in I46.

Named Ranges:
 Range1    Range2

[image: Named Ranges to loop through]
Desired result from macro aftter loop is complete: 
[image: Result]

Code:

```
    For Each Cell In wspGen.Range("Ineligible")
    If Cell.Value = vbNullString Then
        LP.zPledge.Value = "Y"
        wspGen.Range("A46") = "-"
        wspGen.Range("AG55").Value = "X"
    Else
        If Cell.Value = "X" Then
            wspGen.Range("AG55").Value = vbNullString
            wspGen.Range("A45").Value = "N"
            LP.zPledge.Value = "N"
            'Copies the corresponding value from range ("IneligibilityCode")
            'if there is an "X" in any of the cells in range ("Ineligible")
            'to I46.  This could be multiple combinations of values in range ("IneligibilityCode")
        End If
    End If
Next Cell
```

Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: Do you need the same row value from the other named range as where you find the X in the first? If so you can use the .Row where found. If relative positioning then index perhaps.

Comment: Correct.  If "X" is a cell in the the first named range then i would need the corresponding value from the other named range (from image 1).  Im still a novice when it comes to VBA, so would you be able to provide a code example for me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple example using a counter variable assuming both ranges are single column and aligned. It counts how many cells down the first named range 
 (set in variable a) it is before x is found and retrieves the value at the same position in the named range b. Note I am using implicit active sheet references and you should specify the sheet name before the named ranges.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim a As Range, b As Range, rng As Range, counter As Long
    Set a = Range("range1"): Set b = Range("range2")
    For Each rng In a
        counter = counter + 1
        If rng = "x" Then
            Range("I46") = b.Cells(counter)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Space separated list of all matches:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim a As Range, b As Range, rng As Range, counter As Long, outputString As String
    Set a = Range("range1"): Set b = Range("range2")
    For Each rng In a
        counter = counter + 1
        If rng = "x" Then
            outputString = outputString & Chr$(32) & b.Cells(counter)
        End If
    Next
    wspGen.Range("I46")  = Trim$(outputString) ' wspGen.Range("I46")  is defined in your code. This is illustrative.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used that example to change my code, but now im stuck on how to get the values from `InelCode.Cells(counter)` to show up in cell I46. like the example in image 2.

Comment: If they are in the same sheet  Range("I46") = b.Cells(counter)  . Otherwise put the sheet name in front. Worksheets("mySheet").Range("I46") = b.Cells(counter) You should really always use the parent sheet reference.

Comment: I set the `wspGen.Range("I46") = InelCode.Cells(counter)` but it only shows the last value in range 2 that has an "X" in Range 1.  In this case it would be "P".

Comment: Since there may be multiple values from range 2 displayed in "I46", I need all the values from Range 2 that have an "X" in range 1.

Comment: That's easy. You want as a space separated list? See edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience with me and help with this.  It is very much appreciated!

Comment: It's not a problem. Welcome to SO.